# Change a random effects model into a fixed effects model in *BUGS

Tags: self-study, random-effects-model, fixed-effects-model, bugs

I want to manipulate this RE model into a FE model for sensitivity analysis. The model is described here: [Baseline natural history model](http://www.nicedsu.org.uk/TSD5%20Baseline.final%20report.08.05.12.pdf)

```
# Binomial likelihood, logit link
# Baseline random effects model
model{                               # *** PROGRAM STARTS
for (i in 1:ns){                     # LOOP THROUGH STUDIES
 r[i] ~ dbin(p[i],n[i])              # Likelihood
 logit(p[i]) <- mu[i]                # Log-odds of response
 mu[i] ~ dnorm(m,tau.m)              # Random effects model
 }
mu.new ~ dnorm(m,tau.m)              # predictive dist. (log-odds)
m ~ dnorm(0,.0001)                   # vague prior for mean
var.m <- 1/tau.m                     # between-trial variance
tau.m <- pow(sd.m,-2)                # between-trial precision = (1/between-trial variance)
sd.m ~ dunif(0,5)                    # vague prior for between-trial SD
}
```

Would this be a correct way of doing it?

```
# Binomial likelihood, logit link
# Baseline fixed effects model
model{                               # *** PROGRAM STARTS
for (i in 1:ns){                     # LOOP THROUGH STUDIES
 r[i] ~ dbin(p[i],n[i])              # Likelihood
 logit(p[i]) <- mu[i]                # Log-odds of response
 mu[i] ~ dnorm(0,0.0001)              # Fixed effects model
 }
mu.new ~ dnorm(0,0.0001)              # predictive dist. (log-odds)
}
```